# Splitting a string by ],[

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string like the following:

```
"[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]"
```

I was wondering how can I separate the string by `],[` in JavaScript. `.split("],[")` will remove the brackets. I want to preserve them.

Expected output:

```
["[a,b,c]","[d,e,f]","[g,h,i]"]
```

**Edit:**

Here is a more complicated case that I highlighted in a comment on @Leo's answer (wherein a `],[`-delimited string contains `],`):

```
"[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]]"
```

Expected output:

```
["[dfs[dfs],dfs]","[dfs,df,sdfs]]"]
```

Comment: how you want your output

Comment: Do you want `[a,b,c]` `[d,e,f]` `[g,h,i]`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd do

```
"[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]]".split("],[");
```

then loop through it to:

1. Append the first string with a `"]"`.
2. Prepend the last string with a `"["`.
3. Prepend a `"["` and append a `"]"` to all strings in between.

However, if you know what kind of strings and characters you will be receiving and you reaaaaally want a one-liner approach, you could try the hack below.

Replace all instances of `"],["` with `"]unlikely_string_or_special_unicode["`, then split by `"unlikely_string_or_special_unicode"` - for example:

```
"[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]]".replace(/\],\[/g,"]~I_have_a_dream~[").split("~I_have_a_dream~");
```

Warning: Not 100% full-proof. If your input string has the unlikely string you used as a delimiter, then it implodes and the universe comes to an end.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
"[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]".match(/(\[[^\]]+\])/g)
// ["[a,b,c]", "[d,e,f]", "[g,h,i]"]
```

---

**EDIT** For OP's new case, here's the trick:

```
"[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]]".match(/(?!,\[).+?\](?=,\[|$)/g)
// ["[dfs[dfs],dfs]", "[dfs,df,sdfs]]"]
```

It works for even more complicated cases:

```
"[dfs[aa,[a],dfs],[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]]".match(/(?!,\[).+?\](?=,\[|$)/g)
// ["[dfs[aa,[a],dfs]", "[dfs[dfs],dfs]", "[dfs,df,sdfs]]"]

"[dfs[aa,[a],dfs],[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]],[dfs,df,sdfs]]".match(/(?!,\[).+?\](?=,\[|$)/g)
// ["[dfs[aa,[a],dfs]", "[dfs[dfs],dfs]", "[dfs,df,sdfs]]", "[dfs,df,sdfs]]"]
```

---

**Below is my personal opinion**

However, JavaScript's RegExp doesn't support **lookbehind** (`?<`, which is super handy for such requirements), using RegExp may become a maintainability nightmare. In this situation, I'd suggest an approach like, maybe @alienchow's replacing delimiters - not so neat, but more maintainable.

Comment: actually this didnt really solve the issue =[ I am running it on some examples I have and it stops when `],` is found in the string. So "[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]]" will cause more elements to be create rather than 2

Answer (score 2):

### TMTOWDI

I prefer doing this with a regex as @Leo explained, but another way to do it in the spirit of TMTOWDI & completeness is with the [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) following the split:

```js
var test = "[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]";
var splitTest = test.split("],[").map(
    function(str) {
        if (str[0] !== '[') {
            str = '[' + str;
        }
        if (str[str.length - 1] !== ']') {
            str += ']';
        }

        return str;
    });

// FORNOW: to see the results
for (var i = 0; i < splitTest.length; i++) {
    alert(splitTest[i]);
}
```

**Afterthought:**

If you perchance have an empty pair of square brackets in your `],[`-delimited string (i.e. `"[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[],[g,h,i]"` for example), this approach will preserve it too (as would changing @Leo's regex from `/(\[[^\]]+\])/g` to `/(\[[^\]]*\])/g`).

### TMTOWDI Redeux

With the curveball that `]` and `[` may be within the `],[`-delimited strings (per your comment on @Leo's answer), here is a rehash of my initial approach that is more robust:

```js
var test = "[dfs[dfs],dfs],[dfs,df,sdfs]]";
var splitTest = test.split("],[").map(
    function(str, arrIndex, arr) {
        if (arrIndex !== 0) {
            str = '[' + str;
        }
        if (arrIndex !== arr.length - 1) {
            str += ']';
        }

        return str;
    });

// FORNOW: to see the results
for (var i = 0; i < splitTest.length; i++) {
    alert(splitTest[i]);
}
```